# Racing 37 horses, 6 at a time.

Tags: logic, puzzle

I've recently found an extended version of a rather well-known question.

The question goes as follows:

'There are 37 racehorses. You can race them together 6 at a time, and
observe their relative performance. You do not have a timer. How many races
do you need to determine the three fastest horses?'

Here is the link to the solution of the standard version of the puzzle.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/51754/25-horses-find-the-3-fastest-ones

Going by the above solution, it seems to me that the answer to the 37 horses version is 8. Is that correct?

Comment: 37 is not 6^2, it's 1 greater than 6^2.

Comment: @mathlander Although it is one greater, but the construction for 8 races is the similar. The crucial problem is: Whether this construction is the best construction, I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Many problems with this question: per SE guidelines, do not include links to relevant info. please make your post self-contained so that all relevant info is contained therein. also, if by "relative performance" you mean the ranking (1st place, 2nd place, etc) of each horse at the end of a race, then you should say exactly that. Also, the question does not account for random variability in the speed of each horse from race to race. A horse is not necessarily slower than one or more oppoenents because it fails to place $1$st in a single race.

Comment: (continued from above) a better and more accurate question is to ask for the minimum number of races needed to identify the $3$ fastest horses with a given level of confidence.